# Ошибка в сервлете Java - не работает переход по атрибуту href

Tags: java, servlet, href

Реализую учебный сервлет для доски объявлений. Не понимаю, почему по клику на тексте `Посмотреть объявление` не могу перейти на другую страницу (файл). Вместо этого ловлю ошибку `404`.

Скриншот окна
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Доска объявлений</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="GetAttrs" method="post"">
     Авторизуйтесь&nbsp;&nbsp;Автор объявления:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="author" type="text" size="31" /><br>
     Напишите яркий заголовок&nbsp;&nbsp; Текст:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="title" type="text" size="31" /><br>
     Напишите объявление&nbsp;&nbsp; Ваш текст:&nbsp;&nbsp;<textarea name="content" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Разместить">
    <input type="reset" value="Сброс формы">
    <a href="Display.jsp">Посмотреть объявление</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Регистрозависимость, Посмотреть объявление
Display.jsp нужно с маленькой буквы.

2.Форма не закрыта

3.method="post"" лишняя кавычка

Comment: благодарю за указание на мои огрехи. Хотел уточнить по второму пункту: что имеете в виду про закрытие формы?

Comment: нет закрывающего тега </form>